# How to cross domain with CORS in client side?

Tags: javascript, get, header, cors, client

i setup a local web server (127.0.0.1) and i want to fetch content from other domain (http://edge.telin.swiftserve.com) with javascript. but it return a error in console web browser. it said

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://edge.telin.swiftserve.com/live/livetv-mbr/amlst:fa161aa74311/chunklist_b1328000.m3u8?stime=20160907142814&etime=20160907182814&encoded=0157a3207a0dbe56fac02. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)`

i succeful fetch the content if i installed a cors extension in chrome browser and failed to fetch if i'm not install it.

this's the code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" width="640" height="360" controls></video>
<script>
  if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('http://edge.telin.swiftserve.com/live/livetv-mbr/amlst:fa161aa74311/chunklist_b1328000.m3u8?stime=20160907142814&etime=20160907182814&encoded=0157a3207a0dbe56fac02');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
      video.play();
  });
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn about the Same-Origin Policy.  You can't do that.

Comment: @slaks i read some sites said if we can cross domain with cors. if a server and a client support cors. and i think the server is support cors. cause i try it with browser with installed extension cors allow origin. i can fetch the content. so how to make a local server send cors to other domain?

Comment: That extension is exactly the opposite of CORS.  You need to learn what CORS actually is.  You need to make your server send that header.

Comment: @slaks thats extension is client side right? if so how can that extension tell local web server to send custom header to other domain?

Comment: **Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.** This is about the browser, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

you are able to successfully fetch content, because the extension bypasses browser security. this is the reason.

To elaborate, the browser has built-in security to prevent it from making cross-domain requests. This security can be disabled in an extension.

Comment: you can try with chrome browser and install this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi. the video can play. if i disable it. the video can't play. the extension like manipulation something in client side. i think we can with javacript.

Comment: @marcrise: No.  The extension is bypassing all security.  You **need** to understand what CORS is.

Comment: @Slaks if so. how that extension can tell local web server to send custom header to other domain?

Comment: @marcrise It does not tell local web server to send custom header - it does make the browser **ignore** that security policy

Comment: @StefanHegny is it possible with javascript to tell the browser to ignore security policy?

Comment: @marcrise, AFAIK no. If there would be, then malicius sites could use just that to make a hole in the security and make the whole stuff pointless. But plugins can do it, then it is the user hiimself who thows off that security feature. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946536/understanding-cors-on-upnp-dlna-browsing) for a firefox plugin. I had a hard time understanding what it's about too.

Comment: @stefanhegny if so, how this sites can play the url? https://www.hlsplayer.net/. it works perfect. i think its posibble. we need master of javascript here.

Comment: It *might* be that the server side allows these origins specifically. That's what the policy is for. If you find a javascript way of doing it you probably found a security hole.